# "Error in strsplit(version_with_dots, "\\.")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds" for updater function

Tags: r, installr

I am using package installr version 0.17.0 to update R and related packages. However, I get the following error message when I typed `updater()`:

```
Error in strsplit(version_with_dots, "\\.")[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: Maybe try the latest version. Also, please show the code you are using.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I was not using the latest version of the installr package. When I update it to version 0.17.5, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of R is "3.2.4 Revised". installr appears to be having trouble with the " Revised" part of the name. The bug has been fixed in the latest version of the package.